# javascript way to double each element in a multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, multidimensional-array, double

i'm newish to javascript and have been asked to do this test for an apprentiship, i haven't got very far and just needed some help... all i have to do is double each number in the multidimensional array and print it out to the webpage, sorry if this seems simple to some people i am relatively new so don't know an awful lot.

```
        // Define a 2 dimensional (3 x 3) array
        var array = [
            [1, 2, 3],
            [4, 5, 6],
            [7, 8, 9]
        ];


        // TO DO: Double each number in the 2 dimensional array
```

this is all i have so far not sure if i am on the right track??

```
        for (var i = 0; i < array[0].length + array.length; i++){
            for (var j = 0; j <array[0].length +array.length; j++){
            array[i] = array[i] * 2;
                document.write(array[i][j])
                }
            }




        // Output results
        document.write(array.toString(array));

        // Say how big the array is
        document.write("<p>Table is " + array[0].length + " columns by " + array.length + " rows</p>");

        // Start the table
        document.write("<table>");

        // Output the rows
        document.write("<tr><td>" + array[0][0] + "</td><td>" + array[0][1] + "</td><td>" + array[0][2] + "</td></tr>");
        document.write("<tr><td>" + array[1][0] + "</td><td>" + array[1][1] + "</td><td>" + array[1][2] + "</td></tr>");
        document.write("<tr><td>" + array[2][0] + "</td><td>" + array[2][1] + "</td><td>" + array[2][2] + "</td></tr>");

        // End the table
        document.write("</table>");

        // Optionally... make the above "output the rows" code work with
        // any sized array

    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can improve your question. Please read [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). When your code shows your precise problem with nothing extra, you are showing respect to those who volunteer to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) rather than for loops, makes it a little cleaner.

```
var arr = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
];

arr = arr.map(function (sub_arr) {
    return sub_arr.map(function (elem) {
        return elem*2;
    });
});

console.log(arr);
```

**Or optionally using the ES6 syntax**

```
arr = arr.map(sub_arr => sub_arr.map(elem => elem*2));

console.log(arr);
```

Your logic for generating the output is not the best, but it should work fine, although I would use a loop to generate the output rather than statically coding [0][0], [0][1], [0][2], etc...

Answer (score 1):

You may do as follows;

```js
var arrays = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9]
];
for (var array of arrays)
  for (var item of array) logout.textContent += +item * 2 + ",";
```

```html
<pre id="logout"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also loop with forEach like this :

```
arr.forEach(item => item.forEach((elem, index, array) => {array[index] = 2 * elem}));
```